# Help me understand how to index a pixel in an image

Tags: image-manipulation

I had a look at the [code](http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/segment/) for the implementation of this paper  [Graph-Based segmentation](http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf) by Pedro F. Felzenszwalb

But I didn't understand how in the below code that `y * width + x` is used to build a graph from an image.

```
// build graph
edge *edges = new edge[width*height*4];
int num = 0;
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for ( x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        if (x < width-1) {
             edges[num].a = y * width + x;
             edges[num].b = y * width + (x+1);
             edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x+1, y);
             num++;
         }

         if (y < height-1) {
            edges[num].a = y * width + x;
            edges[num].b = (y+1) * width + x;
            edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x, y+1);
            num++;
         }

         if ((x < width-1) && (y < height-1)) {
            edges[num].a = y * width + x;
            edges[num].b = (y+1) * width + (x+1);
            edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x+1, y+1);
            num++;
         }

         if ((x < width-1) && (y > 0)) {
            edges[num].a = y * width + x;
            edges[num].b = (y-1) * width + (x+1);
            edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x+1, y-1);
            num++;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? what specifically you don't understand?

Comment: @gnat the number  y * width + x

Comment: The number y*width+x is the number of the case in the grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 2D matrix can be stored in a 1D vector as a sequence of consecutive fixed-width rows, and the formula for accessing position `(x, y)` is `y*width + x`.

Here's a visual example. Suppose you have a 3x3 matrix filled with `0` and a `$` at position `(1, 2)` (that's column first, row second, **using 0-based indices**). You can store it as a 1D vector as follows:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 $ 0]
```

And here it is visually re-arranged to make sense as a 3x3 matrix:

```
          y
 [0 0 0   0
  0 0 0   1
  0 $ 0]  2

x 0 1 2
```

Because it is a 1D vector (see first figure), we need a single index to get at that `$` value. But because we think of it as a 2D matrix, all we have is the `(1, 2)` location. We need a formula to convert it to a single index.

That formula is the `y*width + x`, like you saw. It roughly means "`y` is how many full rows I have to skip, before moving to the correct column using `x`". Note the formula as written works because we are using 0-based indices, otherwise it requires minor modification.

So in this example, `y = 2`, `x = 1` and `width = 3`:

```
2 * 3 + 1 = 7
```

And index `7` of our original vector `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 $ 0]` has the value `$` that we wanted. (Again, note `7` is a zero-based index).

Answer (score 1):

When you read an image file, it's a linear series of pixels. Let's take an example. Say you have a 32x32 image. This results in a series of 1024 points. In order to get the linear index of the pixel at `y=4` and `x=16`, you'll use the formula `y * witdth + x`, which in this case is `4 * 32 + 16 = 144`